# How to log to syslog from clustered Java application server

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, syslog

My Java EE application, which currently runs on Glassfish 3, is currently using `java.util.logging` to send logmessages. This is intercepted by Glassfish and written to files.

I'd like to switch to a centralised logging solution, since the application is going to be distributed in a cluster.

I have an existing syslog infrastructure. Do you have any suggestion, how to get the application to log to syslog? Glassfish's log-to-syslog feature has no documentation and no configuration, so I haven't considered it much.

What about migrating to SLF4J and using the SLF4J syslog appender?

Comment: Not an answer (hence the comment) but...  I've got a distributed app where each app is using *log4J*'s *SyslogAppender* to append to a remote Linux / syslogd.  I set up this once and it keeps running fine: it was very easy to setup : )

Comment: I was under the impression that syslog only allows you to log a single line, and hence would lose all the useful Java stacktrace information?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look a look at [Glassfish to Syslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243723/glassfish-to-syslog) which shows how to let GlassFish 3 log to system log/syslog via UDP 514 on localhost.

Comment: Thanks, but the provided Syslog functionality of glassfish (`com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.SyslogHandler`) is really bad^H^H^H too simple for production use - you can't configure the facility, severity, format, ... I ended up writing my own SyslogHandler.